# Is it possible to set another language for debugging messages?

Tags: debug, language

The site language is defined as Hebrew. So I get translated error messages.
It's a terrible thing. It is difficult to understand, it is difficult to search on Google, the directions of the text are confused (because some part of the message is written in English /ltr/ and some in Hebrew /rtl/).

Is there any way to keep the site language as Hebrew, but to force the system to output error messages in English?

Comment: What kind of error and where do you get the error messages, can you give an example?

Comment: @birgire For example, if I remove `footer.php` I get: `Notice: תבנית ללא footer.php לא קיים מאז גרסה 3.0.0 ואין תחליף חלופי. יש להוסיף את הקובץ footer.php לתבנית. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\Develop\wp\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4019`. [And since the site has `rtl` direction the message looks like this: http://prntscr.com/m00xzi ]

Comment: The first idea that came to mind was to switch to another locale with `switch_to_locale()`, within a custom PHP error handler set by `set_error_handler()` to override the `trigger_error()`, and then restore the previous one with `restore_previous_locale()`. But the translation seems to have been already evaluated by then, when it's handed down the custom handler, so that approach might not work here. Maybe backtracing (on dev sites) can help with the context or other hooks?

Comment: If you change the locale in your user profile to English, does that help?